# Position of table inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with the following problem, the `12th March` date and table inside are concatenated.

How can I split them?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

UPDATE:[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nurgasemetey/ewuZ7/)

Comment: Please provide HTML & CSS in a JSFiddle

Comment: `table { padding-left: 1em; }` ?

Comment: @Paulie_D, it is rather php file with css and html elements on it, so I can't divide them. How can I do this?

Comment: @nurgasemetey You should get the `HTML`/`CSS` and create a "dummy" page so we can see it. You can use something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). `PHP` etc would only provide the data not the `HTML` or `CSS`. Also I recommend not using a table inside a table...

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, this settings will be applied to upper table, not inner table.

Comment: @nurgasemetey I was hoping you would use your initiative and actually sort that out for yourself. `table.calendar table.events { padding-left: 1em; }` not rocket science dude. Do some reading on CSS...http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Comment: or even `table.calendar table.events { margin-left: 1em; }` this will actually work better

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, I am bit noob in html, doing all this stuff by intuition, so sorry.

Comment: Guys, I pasted link to jfiddle

Comment: @nurgasemetey fair enough man, but still do some basic reading on it. You will probably learn way better methods of doing it with just an hour of research.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, ok I will do, thanks for enduring my noobness

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, by the way it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `div.day-number` style..

```
div.day-number {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

That should sort it out for you.

It is because you are floating the day number so any margin on non-floating elements will be ignored until it impacts another non-floating element. If you add margin to the floating element then you are effectively making it 'wider', hence adding some margin between the floating object and the rest of the content.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewuZ7/2/